# Powershell script not recognizing file in Devops Pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a powershell script in my devops repository called functionapp.ps1 located in a folder called Deploy.

I have the following code line of code in my yml file :

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      filePath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/Deploy/functionapp.ps1'
```

When the stages are being run and it arrives to this task I get the following error:

**##[error]Invalid file path 'D:\a\1\Deploy\functionapp.ps1'. A path to a .ps1 file is required.**

I tried using `filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Deploy/functionapp.ps1'`

I ended up having the same error. Can someone please tell me what is the issue here ?

Comment: You should use command line task to show the value of the default value '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)', and the folder structure in the repo.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I tried using the following filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ExportServiceFunctionApp/Deploy/functionapp.ps1' but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Just as I asked, you need use command line task to show the value of the default value '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)', and the folder structure in your repo.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I tested the command line task. It shows that the working directory have the following name: D:\a\1\s I have no idea from where a\1\s come from. What should I change in this case in the powershell filepath ?

Comment: @Noobie2021  can I check; is your pipeline definitely checking out your source code? If it isn't, that would be an important part of the explanation of what is going wrong.

Comment: @VinceBowdren The source code is being checked out during the build stage. The powershell script is written in the deploy stage after the build is finished. I don't know why at the end of the build stage the directories are getting cleaned and then when it arrives to the deploy stage it is not finding any directory. What do you think could be the problem ?

Comment: Yes, that'll be it. You need to do a fresh checkout in each job.

Comment: @VinceBowdren Thank you very much. You are 100% right. I missed the self in checkout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default directory where your source code files are downloaded is `C:\agent_work\s`
and can be referenced from the build in variable `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`

As a result you will need to use the below filepath on the powershell task:

```
filePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Deploy/functionapp.ps1'
```

You could also use

```
 filePath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/Deploy/functionapp.ps1'
```

If the checkout step for the self (primary) repository has no custom checkout path defined, or the checkout path is the multi-checkout default path `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/<RepoName>` for the self repository, the value of this variable will revert to its default value, which is `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s`

A list with the build in variables can be found from the below URL:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I changed the filepath as you mentioned as the first way it also gave me the following error: ##[error]Invalid file path 'D:\a\1\s\Deploy\functionapp.ps1'. A path to a .ps1 file is required.

Comment: Try also to set your working folder on the powershell script. `workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s'` . Also make sure that the file name is correct. You can make a directory listing using a test powershell before the execution of the actual powershell.

Comment: The working directory ends with the following folder ExportServiceFunctionApp. However, the Deploy mentioned above is not included in the folder. So basically in the repository I have 3 folders: ExportServiceFunctionApp, ExportServiceTests and the Deploy Folder which contains the powershell script.

Comment: Do you think that I should put the powershell script in the same folder as the working Directory ?

Comment: I tried all these ways and nothing worked. It keeps on giving me the same error. Any clue what should I do ?

Comment: Try to add a powershell script before your build step and make a directory listing. Check if files are located within the Deploy folder.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it ? I honestly have no idea. Do you have a code ready for such scenario to get directory listing ?

Comment: add a powershell task with `cd '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s'; ls; cd Deploy; ls`

Comment: I tested the command line task and used script: | echo  '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'. It shows that the working directory have the following name: D:\a\1\s I have no idea from where a\1\s come from. What should I change in this case in the powershell filepath ?

Comment: Maybe you'll know this one as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70834090/azure-pipeline-custom-task-string-input-to-match-regex

Answer (score 0):

You can check the existing file structures in your pipeline by running these lines of code -

```
targetType: 'inline'
script: |
 echo '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
 dir
```

if you do not get any file structures then you can add this line before the path reference -

```
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0
```

> you have no checkout step which is equivalent to checkout: self, your source code is checked out into a directory called s located as a subfolder of (Agent.BuildDirectory). If (Agent.BuildDirectory) is C:\agent_work\1, your code is checked out to C:\agent_work\1\s.

```
fetchDepth: 0
```

Disable shallow fetch which is by-default.